# Can the shell on my host (with my customizations) work with a docker instance?

Tags: shell, docker

Normally if you connect to a docker instance via `docker exec` you land into something quite primitive like `sh` or `ash`.

If you want something better, you have to install it yourself on the docker instance.

However, if I'm looking at it right -- all I want from my shell is to execute binaries and possibly redirect stdin and stdout. Is it not possible for the shell to exist on my host, have the `pwd` of the docker container, and have access to both the binaries of the docker container and my host machine?

This is purely for development / debugging so if I have to disable security features to achieve this, that'd be acceptable.

Can this be easily done? If not, then what are the main roadblocks?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then you want the same shell with the same config in your docker container as in your host system.

You can indeed couple them by using volumes but to get it will be hard and messy to make it work 100% correct. I would strongly suggest installing it and copying the config from your host.

Let's assume on your host you use `bash` as shell and you want to use a container created from the the image `foo:latest` that is based on ubuntu.

In that case you can create the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM foo:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install bash
COPY .bashrc /root/.bashrc
COPY .profile /root/.profile
```

Now:

- Create a dir `newimage`
- Copy `.bashrc` and `.profile` from your homedir to this dir
- Go to this dir and run `docker build -t foo:withbash`

And you will now have a image `foo:withbash` that is the same as `foo:latest` but it will also have bash with it's configuration on your host system.

(The same trick can be done for `zsh` and other shells and centos and other distributions but the commands in the Dockerfile will be slightly different)

**Edit:**
Some notes:

- In my dockerfile I assume that you will be root in your container (which is usually the case). If you are not root in this container you'll probably want to change the last 2 lines so that these files are being copied to the correct dir.
- The 2nd line will work for all dockerimages based on debian, ubuntu or similar distribution.
  If it's based on CentOS or similar distribution you'll want : `yum -y update && yum -y install bash`
  If it's based on Alpine you'll want `RUN apk add --no-cache bash`
- If you want zsh change `bash` to `zsh`  on the 2nd and 3th line

Comment: I did say "If you want something better, you have to install it yourself on the docker instance." so I'm already aware of what you've written. This isn't the question I have.

Comment: Then use `-v /bin/bash:/bin/bash:ro` and `-v /home/youruser/.bashrc:/root/.bashrc:ro` and `-v /home/youruser/.profile:/root/.profile:ro` (in your `docker run` command). But again: This is a terrible practice...